# Making paragraphs with images larger than others

Tags: jquery, html, css, ckeditor

[Here's an image of my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbgft.jpg), just to show what I mean.

So, the h1-tag and paragraph beneath the image both have width:800px; with margin:auto; while the image itself isn't wrapped in a paragraph at all.

I've just began using CKEditor for my project, and this tool wraps pretty much everything in paragraphs - images included.

I'm simply wondering what the best solution for this is? Is there a way to remove the paragraph-tag when a single img-tag is used, or does anyone have a better solution? Would very much appricate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent CKEditor from wrapping everything in a paragraph, just add

```
`config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_xx;`
```

See the api doc for possible values: [API docs](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-enterMode)